# Redirect old directory to new directory IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, plesk

We used to have our website on a directory like this www.example.com/web/ and now we moved to IIS and removed the "web" directory.

How do I redirect the requests from www.example.com/web/ to www.example.com/ in IIS? And is it possible to only redirect the "/web/" directory?

Many of our visitors had bookmarks so now they are seeing dead links.

Comment: The jargon is to *"rewrite"* requests or to create a *"rewrite rule"* in the IIS Rewrite Module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and configure the URL Rewrite module

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: This is the rule I used:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="web to normal" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="web/([_0-9a-z-]+\.(php)$)" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://yourwebsite.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>